# Cassandra ReadTimeout: code=1200 - Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I've got 3 node cluster on DSE 4.8.8 with replication factor = 2 and consistency on write quorum and on read one. When I'm trying to select some of the data I get this error:

```
cqlsh:production> SELECT * FROM cass_visitors WHERE domain_id = 364 LIMIT 1;
ReadTimeout: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
cqlsh:production>
```

On some domain_ids it works, and on some it doesn't. What can be a cause of this?